# I want to display a selection from the database in a listBox and I have some problems. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Tags: c#

when i run the program it shows me something like this in the list:"System.Data.DataRow" I'll put pictures

```cs
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=...;" +
            "User=...;" +
            "Password=...;";

    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

    con.Open();

    string select = "select PRODUCT  from TBLPRODUCTSIM  where SOLVERTYPES like " + "'%"+GlobalVariable+"%'";
    OracleDataAdapter bb = new OracleDataAdapter(select, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    bb.Fill(dt);

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows )
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(row.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use `row.ToString()` This will print the implementation of the ToString method for DataRow which shows you the type.

To show the products:

Use `row["PRODUCT"].ToString();`